# E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main --- android application java

Tags: javascript, java, android

I am doing the map application and I met some problem. 
Anyone know what happened to my code?

ERROR

```
10-25 01:37:41.296 28673-28673/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-25 01:37:41.296 28673-28673/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.onemap.activities, PID: 28673
10-25 01:37:41.296 28673-28673/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.onemap.activities/com.onemap.activities.OneMap}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.widget.TextView
10-25 01:37:41.296 28673-28673/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2596)
10-25 01:37:41.296 28673-28673/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2653)
10-25 01:37:41.296 28673-28673/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
10-25 01:37:41.296 28673-28673/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
10-25 01:37:41.296 28673-28673/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-25 01:37:41.296 28673-28673/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
10-25 01:37:41.296 28673-28673/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
10-25 01:37:41.296 28673-28673/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-25 01:37:41.296 28673-28673/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-25 01:37:41.296 28673-28673/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
10-25 01:37:41.296 28673-28673/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
10-25 01:37:41.296 28673-28673/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-25 01:37:41.296 28673-28673/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.widget.TextView
10-25 01:37:41.296 28673-28673/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
10-25 01:37:41.296 28673-28673/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
10-25 01:37:41.296 28673-28673/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
10-25 01:37:41.296 28673-28673/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
10-25 01:37:41.296 28673-28673/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
10-25 01:37:41.296 28673-28673/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
10-25 01:37:41.296 28673-28673/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
10-25 01:37:41.296 28673-28673/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
10-25 01:37:41.296 28673-28673/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.onemap.fragments.MainMenu.onCreateView(MainMenu.java:88)
10-25 01:37:41.296 28673-28673/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1965)
10-25 01:37:41.296 28673-28673/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1047)
10-25 01:37:41.296 28673-28673/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1237)
10-25 01:37:41.296 28673-28673/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1339)
10-25 01:37:41.296 28673-28673/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2295)
10-25 01:37:41.296 28673-28673/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:111)
10-25 01:37:41.296 28673-28673/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:314)
10-25 01:37:41.296 28673-28673/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31)
10-25 01:37:41.296 28673-28673/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
10-25 01:37:41.296 28673-28673/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
10-25 01:37:41.296 28673-28673/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
10-25 01:37:41.296 28673-28673/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
10-25 01:37:41.296 28673-28673/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
10-25 01:37:41.296 28673-28673/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
10-25 01:37:41.296 28673-28673/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
10-25 01:37:41.296 28673-28673/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
10-25 01:37:41.296 28673-28673/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:375)
10-25 01:37:41.296 28673-28673/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1997)
10-25 01:37:41.296 28673-28673/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.onemap.activities.OneMap.onCreate(OneMap.java:57)
10-25 01:37:41.296 28673-28673/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5312)
10-25 01:37:41.296 28673-28673/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
```

**ONEMAP.java**

The error at `setContentView(R.layout.onemap);`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.onemap);

        AppUtilities.init(this);
        favDB = new FavouritesDBHandler(AppUtilities.getContext());

        this.scrollView = (SlidingMenu) findViewById(R.id.mScrollView);
        View mainContent = this.scrollView.getMainContent();
        OnClickListener clickListener = getClickListener();
        OnLongClickListener longClickListener = getLongClickListener();
        mainContent.findViewById(R.id.mScreenToggle).setOnClickListener(clickListener);
        JewelContainer jewelContainer = (JewelContainer) mainContent.findViewById(R.id.jewel_container);
        jewelContainer.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
        jewelContainer.setOnLongClickListener(longClickListener);
        LotViewSlider lotSlider = (LotViewSlider) mainContent.findViewById(R.id.mSeekLot);
        lotSlider.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(getLotSliderListener());
        lotSlider.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        this.mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mMapView);
        this.mMapView.setOnStatusChangedListener(OneMapStatusListener.getInstance());
        this.mMapView.setOnSingleTapListener(getSingleTapListener());
        this.mMapView.setOnLongPressListener(getLongPressListener());
        this.mMapView.setCalloutClickListener(getClickListener());
        this.mMapView.getCallout().setMaxWidth(550);
    }
```

**MAINMENU.java**

The error at `inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_main, rl);`

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.menu_content);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_main, rl);
        ListView menuList = (ListView) rl.findViewById(R.id.menu_list);
        menuList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        menuList.setOnScrollListener(this);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.arrowUp = (ImageView) rl.findViewById(R.id.iv_arrow_up);
        viewHolder.arrowDown = (ImageView) rl.findViewById(R.id.iv_arrow_down);
        menuList.setTag(viewHolder);
        MenuItem[] arrayMenuItem = new MenuItem[5];
        arrayMenuItem[0] = new MenuItem(0, "Services", R.mipmap.ic_menu_title_service);
        arrayMenuItem[1] = new MenuItem(1, getString(R.string.get_directions), R.mipmap.ic_directions);
        arrayMenuItem[2] = new MenuItem(2, getString(R.string.amenities), R.mipmap.ic_amenities);
        arrayMenuItem[3] = new MenuItem(3, "Others", R.mipmap.ic_menu_title_other);
        arrayMenuItem[4] = new MenuItem(4, getString(R.string.about), R.mipmap.ic_about);
        menuList.setAdapter(new MenuAdapter(getActivity(), arrayMenuItem));
        return v;
    }
```

Here is my XML File

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.onemap.widgets.MapView
        xmlns:callout="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.onemap.activities"
        android:id="@id/mMapView"
        calloutStyle="@xml/callout_style"
        initExtent="29454.233386372267 39831.55546813806 30038.01821247406 40758.313879574656"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        callout:layout="@layout/callout" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <com.onemap.widgets.SlidingMenu
        xmlns:menu="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.onemap.activities"
        android:id="@id/mScrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        menu:main_content="@id/mainContainer"
        menu:menu_content="@id/menuContainer"
        menu:menu_handle="@id/handle"
        menu:menu_marginRight="@dimen/menu_margin_r">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <fragment
                android:id="@id/menuContainer"
                class="com.onemap.fragments.MainMenu"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:tag="MainMenu"
                tools:layout="@layout/menu_main" />

            <include
                android:id="@id/mainContainer"
                layout="@layout/widgets" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </com.onemap.widgets.SlidingMenu>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: There should be another portion of your stack trace, with another "Caused by", explaining what exception triggered the `InflateException`. Beyond that, you should post the layout file that is triggering the crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you set the views is wrong, I adjusted the code for you:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //set the main view change hello_world to the correct layout_name.xml file
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hello_world, container, false);

    //set the other views
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    viewHolder.arrowUp = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iv_arrow_up);
    viewHolder.arrowDown = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iv_arrow_down);

    ListView menuList = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.menu_list);
    menuList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    menuList.setOnScrollListener(this);
    menuList.setTag(viewHolder);

    MenuItem[] arrayMenuItem = new MenuItem[5];
    arrayMenuItem[0] = new MenuItem(0, "Services", R.mipmap.ic_menu_title_service);
    arrayMenuItem[1] = new MenuItem(1, getString(R.string.get_directions), R.mipmap.ic_directions);
    arrayMenuItem[2] = new MenuItem(2, getString(R.string.amenities), R.mipmap.ic_amenities);
    arrayMenuItem[3] = new MenuItem(3, "Others", R.mipmap.ic_menu_title_other);
    arrayMenuItem[4] = new MenuItem(4, getString(R.string.about), R.mipmap.ic_about);

    menuList.setAdapter(new MenuAdapter(getActivity(), arrayMenuItem));

    return v;
}
```

The view holder code should probably move to your custom adapter `MenuAdapter`